# How to check maximum length for apex:inputtextarea using Javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I use **jqEasyCounter javascript library** to validate maximum character in `apex:inputtextarea`.

I got one bug whereby it wont count first character at the first time.Mean if we type **'1'** in text area it will detect as **Characters: 0/500** while it should mentioned as **1/500** .

After that, it works fine.I tried to check on this library but it seem nowhere to refer.Check out the link [here](http://www.jqeasy.com/), seem like it gone already.

Here is my snippet,I called this javascript in document.ready function.

```
function txtareacus(){

    $('.txtaresexpone').jqEasyCounter({
                   'maxChars': 300,
                    'maxCharsWarning': 290
                });          
     $('.txtaresexpone').BetterGrow({                    
                    do_not_enter: false,
                    on_enter:   function() {
                                    $('.area7_flag').css('visibility', 'visible');     
                                }
                });                                           
}

 <apex:inputTextArea style="border: none;width:420px;resize:none;" styleclass="txtaresexpone" value="{!c.Comments__c}" />
```

Is anyone using jqEasyCounter?Or any other javascript library to check maximum character in visualforce?

Comment: I don't see any issue with that. it is working fine for me. try to use following version. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5FQvDdE4z0PZU9JdC1mVk1BU28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you do not need all the bells and whistles have you tried the `maxlength` property of the input text component?

Comment: @Himanshu I compared the code.Exactly the same.The thing that makes me itchy because it show correctly after we save the character ,but then after type       it will treat first character as zero,second as 1.I am not sure why.

Comment: @Eric , I know we can use this html-maxlength="500" , but user would like to have character count,warning in the bottom of the text area.

Comment: can you try after removing value="{!c.Comments__c}"

Comment: removed but still same behaviour

Comment: how you call it @Himanshu ,you put in document ready?mind to share ur code.you can put it in answer , i can try it and see if it works.